# Xamarin / iOs / MSBuild: random build crash with “The Build Agent is not running on the Mac”

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, msbuild

We’ve recently upgraded our local Windows CI server building our Xamarin solution to the latest VS2017. Before it was still using VS2015.
Since that time, about 30% of our build fails randomly with the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
 Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Windows.After.targets(63,5):
 warning : Failed to execute 'which mono64': ExitStatus = 1  C:\Program
 Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
 Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Windows.After.targets(63,5):
 error : The Build Agent 'Build 4.8.0.753' is not running on the Mac.
 Please ensure that the assembly versions between the XMA Agents and
 the XMA clients matches. A compatible Build Agent is needed in order
 to finish the build.
```

On the Mac build log, here is what we get:

```
 Xamarin.Messaging.Build.BuildAgent: Information: 0: Stopping Agent:
 Build: 2018-01-09 10:12:44Z System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.MqttClientImpl: Error:
 0: No session has been found for the client at
 System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.MqttClientImpl.CloseClientSession () [0x00098] in
 <65aadb65fa...> at System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.MqttClientImpl+d__34.MoveNext
 () [0x00035] in <65aadb65fa...> System.Net.Mqtt.Sdk.MqttClientImpl:
 Information: 0: Client - Disposing. Reason: Error:
```

`Xamarin.iOS.Windows.After.targets` line 63 runs the SayHello MSBuild task, so it looks like that's the one that randomly fails even tough the connection to the Mac is alive and running.

The versions we are using on both our Windows machine and Mac mini:
Windows:

- Visual Studio 2017, version 15.5.2
- Windows 2012r2
- Java Development Kit 8u152
- Xamarin 4.8.0.753
- Xamarin Designer 4.8.188
- Xamarin.Android SDK 8.1.0.25
- Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK 11.6.1.2

Mac:

- Visual Studio 2017 for Mac, version 7.3.2.12
- Mac OS X 10.13.2
- Mono: 5.4.1.7
- Xamarin.Android 8.1.0.25
- Xamarin.iOS 11.6.1.2
- Xamarin.Mac 4.0.0.214

Any idea?
How can we make this more stable?

Comment: We've seen similar behavior, and I found your bugzilla post here https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=61156 we're in the same boat, I've posted an "Answer" that contains our research but by no means do I think its the actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

We've seen similar behavior (and are running almost an identical setup). I am unsure if this is related but often times we'll log out to the mac in question and we'll see that a dialog has popped up asking for credentials; specifically:

[image: codesign wants to access key "access" in your keychain. To allow this, enter the "login" keychain password]

"codesign wants to access key "access" in your keychain. To allow this, enter the "login" keychain password"

We've been entering in the login password and saying "Always Allow" after doing this several times (we have lots of iOS Projects) our builds eventually go through and are "stable". However this cycle seems to reset anytime we have to reassign our iOS Developer Keys.

Again because the issue is so random its hard to say if its related, but it sure seems like it.